# Series Summation involving factorials, and powers.

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

What is the value of

$\dfrac{1.2}{3!} + \dfrac{2.2^2}{4!} + \dfrac{3.2^3}{5!} + ...... + \dfrac{15.2^{15}}{17!}$

How would you proceed with this?

I attempted writing the general term and tried some manipulations with it but couldn't get anywhere.
Any hint would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your sum is
$$\sum_{n=1}^{15} \dfrac{n \cdot 2^n}{(n+2)!} = \sum_{n=1}^{15} \left(\dfrac{(n+2) \cdot 2^n}{(n+2)!} - \dfrac{ 2^{n+1}}{(n+2)!} \right) = \sum_{n=1}^{15} \left(\dfrac{2^n}{(n+1)!} - \dfrac{ 2^{n+1}}{(n+2)!} \right)$$
which gives us (by telescoping series)
$$\dfrac{2}{2!} - \dfrac{2^2}{3!} + \dfrac{2^2}{3!} - \dfrac{2^3}{4!} \pm \cdots + \dfrac{2^{15}}{16!} - \dfrac{2^{16}}{17!} = 1 - \dfrac{2^{16}}{17!}$$
And in general,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac{n \cdot 2^n}{(n+2)!} = 1 - \dfrac{2^{m+1}}{(m+2)!}$$